# OpenCSV Avoid using FileWriter and return InputStream

Tags: java, csv, inputstream, java-7, opencsv

I am using OpenCsv and the `new CSVWriter()` method takes a Writer as an argument.

What I am trying to achieve is that to avoid writing to the file system and instead return an `InputStream`. I am not sure how to go about this. Not very familiar with `Streams` also I am using `JAVA 7`.

Is it possible that I could make the writeValues method return an InputStream and avoid writing the output on file system.

This is my working implementation:

```
private static void writeValues(String[][] cellValues) throws IOException {

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/myfile.csv"));
    for(String[] row : cellValues) { 
        writer.writeNext(row);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

This is what I want to achieve.
How to Convert the above method to avoid using a FileWriter.

```
private static InputStream writeValues(String[][] cellValues) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = ?;

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(?);
    for(String[] row : cellValues) { 
        writer.writeNext(row);
    }
    writer.close();

    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of returning a consumed `ByteArrayInputStream()`? And what was the result of this attempt?

Comment: I was able to figure out the problem. The CSVWriter needs to be closed before writing to file. I was not using the result of the return value as I was writing a file on disk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write to an `OutpuStreamWriter` itself writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and in the end, you'll have a byte array in memory (by calling `getBytes()` on the `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

You can then read from this byte array by opening a `ByteArrayInputStream` on the byte array.

Comment: Can you share your code here as to how you used OutputStreamWriter? I am in the same boat trying to avoid writing to a file and directly return InputStream.

Answer (score 19):

An example implementation to convert Beans to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] getBeansAsByteArray(final List<YourBean> beans) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(streamWriter);

    StatefulBeanToCsv<YourBean> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
    beanToCsv.write(beans);
    streamWriter.flush();
    
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Grab a working snippet without StatefulBeanToCsv which I do not prefer.

```
 String[] headers = { "id", "result", "searchTerm"};
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(streamWriter);
 writer.writeNext(headers);
 // listOfRows -> business logic collection containing data for csv rows, as you can see I've separated the declaration of headers 
 listOfRows.forEach(it -> {
        writer.writeNext(new String[] {it.getId().toString(), it.getResult(), it.getSearchTerm()});
 });

 streamWriter.flush();
 byte[] byteArrayOutputStream = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is correct implementation**

```
public static byte[] getBeansAsByteArray(List<YourBean> beans) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(streamWriter);

    StatefulBeanToCsv<YourBean> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
    beanToCsv.write(beans);
    streamWriter.flush();

    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell, see this line CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(streamWriter);